# Daemons process on MacOS and DNS server

Tags: macos, dns

I've written my own server and I run it as daemon on MacOS 10. It works well. 
My server makes a request `R` to address `https://any_address.com`. IP address of that hostname is resolved using my local DNS server. And everything works as I am expecting.

When I logout from MacOS (I don't turn off a system, just logging out) the server is still enabled and it works. (I can communicate to it). But, when server tries make a request `R` to `https://any_address.com` there is an error:

`Could not resolve hostname [hostname]: nodename nor servname provided, or not known`.
It suggests that something about DNS is wrong.

When I log in and when I **restart** the server it works again.